# Cheese and Skype not recognizing the camera

Tags: drivers, 18.04, dell, webcam

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 on Dell Inspiron n5110. However Cheese and Skype is not recognizing the camera.

```
$ lspci
{00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)}
{00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)}
{00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)}
{00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)}
{00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)}
{00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)}
{00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b4)}
{00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b4)}
{00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b4)}
{00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev b4)}
{00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 8 (rev b4)}
{00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)}
{00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM67 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)}
{00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port Mobile SATA AHCI Controller (rev 04)}
{00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)}
{01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 525M] (rev a1)}
{01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)}
{05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 05)}
{09:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)}
{0b:00.0 USB controller: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 04)}
```

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: There's no camera listed which means it isn't using USB internally. Can you try `lspci` and then [edit] and update your question (Please use {} and paste inside to format it as code).

Comment: I believe your laptop is dual-booted. Is your webcam detected in Windows 10? Does it work in Windows 10? Please post the output of the following commands: 1. `ls -lh /dev/video*` 2. `lsmod | grep uvcvideo` and 3. `dmesg | grep -i "Camera"`

Comment: Please restart you computer and press `del` key to enter into BIOS setup screen. Look through the BIOS options for an entry labeled something like `webcam`, `integrated camera`, or `CMOS camera`. Do you find any such entry?  If so, is the webcam enabled?

Comment: There is no such entry.

Comment: 1. ls -lh /dev/video --- No such file or directory

Comment: 2. lsmod | grep uvcvideo --- Does nothing

Comment: 3. dmesg | grep -i "Camera" --- Does nothing

Comment: Few years ago when i was using this laptop with an earlier Ubuntu everything was fine. I do not have windows installed atm.